# cloudformation composer install

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, aws-cloudformation

So I am using cloudformation for my AWS setup, I am trying to run composer but for some reason no matter what command I put in my userdata section I always can an error, this is my error:

```
php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar create-project composer/satis /var/www/satis --stability=dev

  [RuntimeException]                                                                        
  The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly
```

This is my code within the userdata section:

```
"#composer\n",
"curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php\n",
"mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar\n",

"#satis\n",
"php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar create-project composer/satis /var/www/satis --stability=dev\n",
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might not work and should I should be doing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Composer is looking for the location of the .composer directory. Export the HOME or COMPOSER_HOME env variable, e.g. : HOME=/root php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar create-project composer/satis /var/www/satis --stability=dev, it will work fine then.

Comment: Im having the same issue but it doesn't even seem to install composer. The error log file says:`All settings correct for using Composer` then `The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly` I am running the exact command stated. When i ssh into the instance and type composer it doesn't work and the composer file is not in the expected location.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with amazon linux ami 2, it was showing in the log `All settings correct for using Composer. The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly`, but it was not installed at all. Below is the way to fix it. Might be helpful to somebody rather waisting 2,3 hours!

```
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
chmod +x /usr/bin/composer
export COMPOSER_HOME=/root
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ntwobike's answer.

When launching AWS EC2 instances I was installing composer by running an Ansible playbook during in the user data script run.  (The user data script is called by cloud-init during the instance build process).

For some reason at this point in the build the $HOME environment variable is not set.  So I needed to add 'export HOME=/root' - e.g.

```
# These need to be set to enable the composer installer to run.  It is probably due to an issue                                                                                                                                  
# with the $HOME variable not yet being set at this point in the instance creation.                                                                                                                                              
export HOME=/root
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "target=localhost"  playbooks/debian-9/drush.yml
```